# sort the solr search result. give error can not sort on multivalued field: name

Tags: solr, lucene

I am newer to the Apache Solr search.

I am trying to sort the result set in the Solr query.
Query : name:abc* AND hidden:false & sort=name desc

It's showing the error :
can not sort on the multivalued field: name

Solr version is: 7.2.1

Comment: If you don't intend to have the field `name` represent multiple values, you probably want to make the field single valued (i.e. define `multiValued="false"` for the field).

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using recent versions of the Solr (>5.3) you should be able to use min or max functions to do sorting on multivalued fileds like this:

```
sort=field(field_to_sort_on,min) asc
```

The only requirement to achieve this is to use DocValues on this field - so finding minimum/maximum on multivalued field could be achieved efficiently