# Sort the search result in ascending order of a multivalued field in Solr

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, solr

I'm using Solr of `version 6.6.0`. I have a schema of title (text_general), description(text_general), id(integer). When I search for a keyword to list the results in ascending order of the title my code returns an error **can not sort on multivalued field: title.**

I have tried to set the sort using the following 3 methods

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
1. query.setSort("title", SolrQuery.ORDER order);
2. query.addSort("title", SolrQuery.ORDER order);
3. SortClause ab = new SolrQuery.SortClause("title", SolrQuery.ORDER.asc);
   query.addSort(ab);
```

but all of these returns the same error

I found a solution by referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091121/sort-the-solr-search-result-give-error-can-not-sort-on-multivalued-field-name)

It says to use min/max functions. 
query.setSort(field("pageTitle",min), ORDER.asc);
this what I'm trying to set as the query, I didn't understand what are the arguments used here.

This is the maven dependency that I'm using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I suggest adding the `solr` tag to this question, so the Solr experts will find it. This is less about `maven` or `spring-mvc` than it is about `solr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `title` actually is multiValued - can your post have multiple titles - you should [define it as `multiValued="false"` in your schema](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/defining-fields.html#DefiningFields-OptionalFieldTypeOverrideProperties). However, there's a second issue - a field of the default type `text_general` isn't suited for sorting, as it'll generate multiple tokens, one for each word in the title. This is useful for searching, but will give weird and non-intuitive results when sorting.

So instead, define a `title_sort` field and [use a field type with a `KeywordTokenizer`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-KeywordTokenizer) and [`LowerCaseFilter` attached](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-LowerCaseFilter) (if you want case insensitive sort), or if you want case sensitive sort, use the already defined `string` field type for the `title_sort` field.

Comment: I have set `mulitvalued="false"` in my schema, now the search is working. But the sorting is not in alphabetical order. Somehow it returns like the following order.
`A & B Religious Shop`,
`A Shower of Roses Religious Shop`,
`Abundant Graces Books & Gifts`,
`Angelic Accents`,
`Purple Armadillo Again, LLC`,
`AGAPE Christian Books and Gifts.`
I couldn't understand in what order the search is working here. Even the direct search from Solr is also returning in the same order

Comment: This is because your field is still a `text` field and not a `string` field or a field type with just the `KeywordTokenizer` attached. See the second paragraph in my answer.

Comment: Also be aware that changing the type requires a reindex in most cases (such as this one).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Initially, I have defined the title field as a string variable in Solr schema. However, it returns an error on indexing the data. I have tried with `String` and `Strings` in the schema, in both cases, my java code returns the error log  `"can not change DocValues type from SORTED_SET to SORTED for field "title" "`, that's why I used `text_general` type. Also, only the `text_general` type variable allow the case insensitive search result.

Comment: The error is caused by changing the type of an existing field for an index with existing data. You'll have to clear out the index first before reindexing (and changing the type). You can use different fields with different types for searching and for sorting - so for searching, use a field type with `text_general`, but for sorting, use a field type with `string` (or if you want a case insensitive sort, use a `TextField` with a `KeywordTokenizer` and an lowercasefilter attached).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is do you really need that title field to be multivalued, or do your documents really have multiple titles ? If not, you just need to fix the field definition by setting `multivalued="false"`.

That said, sorting on a multivalued field doesn't make sense unless determining which one of these multiple values should be used to sort on, or how to combine them into one.

Let' say we need to sort a given resultset by title (alphabetically), first using a single-valued title field :

```
# Unsorted
"docs": [
  { "id": "1", "title": "One" },
  { "id": "2", "title": "Two" },
  { "id": "3", "title": "Three" },
]

# Sorted
"docs": [
  { "id": "1", "title": "One" },
  { "id": "3", "title": "Three" },
  { "id": "2", "title": "Two" },
]

# -> ok no problem here
```

Now applying the same logic with a multi-valued field is not possible as is, you would necessarily need to determine which title to use in each document to properly sort them :

```
# Unorted
"docs": [
  { "id": "1", "title": ["One", "z-One", "a-One"] },
  { "id": "2", "title": ["Two", "z-Two", "a-Two"] },
  { "id": "3", "title": ["Three", "z-Three", "a-Three"] }
]
```

Fortunately, Solr allows to sort results by the output of a function, meaning you can use any from Solr's [function queries](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html) to "get" a single value per title field. The answer you referred to is a good example even though it may not work for you (because title would need docValues enabled - depends on field definition - and knowing that max/min functions should be used only with numeric values), just to get the idea :

```
# here the 2nd argument is a callback to max(), used precisely to get a single value from title
sort=field(title,max) asc
```